# Use SVG groups as more complex version of bars in D3 charts

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Assume I have some complex data visualization built with D3. 
I want to add not just basic rects of different sizes, but create sets of units built from groups of different graphics, like having some rectangle, triangle pointer, text label and background rectangle in a single group element.

Primarily I run `var unit = d3.select('.unit').data(units).enter().append('g')` to create these containers. Now How do I properly add inner content so that it doesn't add multiple dupe items on each data update with simple `unit.append('rect')`?

Now I have to do something like this `if (!unit.select('.label').size()){//append the element} else {//update existing element}`.

If I have e.g. 5 elements inside a unit, it easily becomes look ugly with all these `if..then`.

Is there a better way to manage cases like this?

Comment: Are you looking for [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/)?

Comment: I don't think it's the case to use nested selections as what I want to add is just a set of single elements, not series of them, which can reflect the data that is bound to their parent, like unit, `g` element which contains them.

Comment: I don't see the problem then -- just add on the enter selection and select on the update selection.

Comment: if the dataset is a nested array or a series of objects, you can also use the .each() function to append elements to each group based on some criteria

Comment: Lars, so I should run all these `if exists then modify otherwise append then modify`?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you don't need these explicit checks. You append only for the enter selection and modify for the update selection (when you know that the elements will be there because you've appended them before).

Answer (score 0):

You can move complex drawings to the separate function

```
var unit = d3.selectAll('.unit').data(units);

// ENTER
unit.enter().append('g')
    .attr('class', 'unit')
    // ... transform and other unit-level stuff here

// UPDATE
unit.transition().duration()
    .call(drawUnit);

// EXIT
unit.exit()
    .remove();
```

And in the `drawUnit` function you can write something like this:

```
function drawUnit(units) {
    units.each(function(d) {
        var unit = d3.select(this); // select g.unit
        // DRAW LABEL
        var label = unit.selectAll('text')
            .data([d]); // rejoin data from the unit to the label

        // enter
        label.enter()
            .append('text');

        // update
        label
            .text(function(d) { return d.label; });

        // exit
        // if you need to hide the labels then instead of `.data([d])` you can
        // use something like this `.data(d.label.length ? [d] : [])`
        // label.exit().remove();


        // draw other inner elements of the unit
        // DRAW ARROW
        var arrow = unit.selectAll('.arrow').data([d]);
        // ....
    });
}
```

Here is JSFiddle with more comments: http://jsfiddle.net/fd6o4eey/1/